# Alert() not showing

Tags: javascript

I have such a simple javascript exercise problem that I cannot get to display. I've gotten other alerts to work but I am not sure how to call this one out properly. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function multa(a, b) {
        return c; 
        var a = 3;
        var b = 4; 
      }
      alert(a * b + "is" + c);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your JS console--scoping matters. Unrelated: what do you believe that function will do when you call it?

Comment: You're apparently a beginner so the best piece of advice I can give is, learn how to use Chrome Devtools, make snippets and create breakpoints. You can watch your code hit each line to better understand what's happening. In this case, you'd find that the internals of the `multa` function never happen, because you never call the function, so `a` and `b` never get set.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your variables outside the function, you have to declare them in an outer scope.

```html
<html>
  <script>
    let a = 3;
    let b = 2;
    function multiple(a, b) {
      return a * b;
    }
    alert(multiple(a, b));
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    <script>
      function multa(a,b) {
        var c=a*b;
        return c; 
      }
      var a = 3;
      var b = 4; 
      alert (a +"*"+ b + " is " + multa(a,b));
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, variable declarations are scoped (fancy term for how long a variable would be available for) differently based on which keyword (`var`, `let`, `const`) you use to declare the variable.

For simplicity sake, `let` and `const` are scoped in a similar way i.e they're available within a block scope they were defined in.

For example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log(i); // this will give an error as `i` is available only within the for loop block
```

Here's where `var` is slightly different; a variable declared with `var` is hoisted (pushed up) to the top of the function it was declared in.

If there's no function, the scope is global.

Example:

```
function Test() {
  console.log(i); // logs `undefined` instead of an error.
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

The way JS "interprets" this function after hoisting is as follows,

```
function Test() {
  var i // notice the declaration has moved to the top - which wasn't the case with `let` and `const`
  console.log(i);
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Now in your case,

```
function multa(a, b) {
    return c; 
    var a = 3;
    var b = 4; 
}
alert(a * b + "is" + c);
```

This will be interpreted as,

```
function multa(a, b) {
    var a; // declaration is hoisted
    var b; // declaration is hoisted
    return c; 
    a = 3;
    b = 4; 
}
alert(a * b + "is" + c);
```

Now when JS tries to execute the alert, it can't find variables `a`, `b` and `c` because their scope is limited to the function they were declared in.

So you'd need to change this to,

```
function multa(a, b) {
    var a; // declaration is hoisted
    var b; // declaration is hoisted
    var c;



    a = 3;
    b = 4;
    c = a * b


    alert("a * b is" + c);
}
```

Changes:

- A `return` statement is not necessary
- Need a variable `c`
- "a*b" needs to be in quotes, else you'll just get an alert "12 is 12" since JS will compute `a * b`